# Node.js memory leak hunting without v8-profiler

Tags: javascript, memory, node.js, memory-leaks, profiler

I'm trying to track down a memory leak in a Node.js app. I've tried installing v8-profiler but it will not compile... it looks like a [dead project](https://github.com/dannycoates/v8-profiler/issues/29#issuecomment-39050153) that a lot of people are trying to use but getting the same problem - pretty-much from about node 0.3.2 so quite a while ago.

Does anyone know of a way to hunt down memory leaks in a Node.js app without using v8-profiler? I have Eclipse running with the V8 remote debugging working but cannot find a way to see memory usage / heaps etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you looked at https://github.com/felixge/node-memory-leak-tutorial? The author includes a link in the Readme to a more recent (Apr 11) fork of v8-profiler.

Comment: Hi, yes I found that in my googling but that version of v8-profiler also fails to compile with Node 0.6.10.

Comment: Looks like v8-profiler has been updated to support Node 0.6.10, I'll test it out and post back if it works ok.

Comment: Were you ever able to successfully profile the memory of your nodejs app?

Comment: Profiler does not work, see the issues list on the project.  This project appears to be dead.

Comment: Also v8 profiler doesn't seem to scale - a snapshot of 500mb heap takes forever.